# How to serialize Inherited models in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django Rest Framework project, in which I have created the following models as:

```
from django.db import models

# Base Models...
choices = (
    ('Single', 'Single'),
    ('Multiple', 'Multiple'),
)


class UserAccountModel(models.Model):
    deployment_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    credentials = models.FileField(upload_to='media/credentials/', name='credentials'),
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, name='project_id')
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    zone_region = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deployment_name


class AwdModel(UserAccountModel):
    source_zip = models.FileField(upload_to='media/awdSource/', name='awd_source')
    routing = models.TextField(name='routing', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deployment_name

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing:
            raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
        super().save(**kwargs)

    # def clean(self):
    #     if self.services == 'Multiple' and self.routing is None:
    #         raise ValidationError('You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.')


class AwodModel(UserAccountModel):
    source_zip = models.FileField(upload_to='media/awodSource/', name='awod_source')
    routing = models.TextField({'type': 'textarea'}, name='routing')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing:
            raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

I need to serialize these models, Here's how I have implemented serializers for these models:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UserAccountModel, AwdModel, AwodModel


class UserAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccountModel
        fields = ('deployment_name', 'credentials', 'project_name',
                  'project_id', 'cluster_name', 'zone_region', 'services')


class AWDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(UserAccountSerializer.Meta):
        model = AwdModel
        fields = UserAccountSerializer.Meta.fields + ('awd_source', 'routing',)


class AWODSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AwodModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

But, when I try to access, AWDSerialzer it return an error as:

> AttributeError at /api/v1/deployments/
>   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `project_id` on serializer `AWDSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'project_id'.

**Update: Here's my APIView code:**

```
class DeploymentsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        MAX_OBJECTS = int(20)
        deployments = AwdModel.objects.all()[:MAX_OBJECTS]
        data = AWDSerializer(deployments).data
        return Response(data)


class DeploymentDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        deployment = get_object_or_404(AwdModel, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        data = AWDSerializer(deployment).data
        return Response(data)
```

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your `AWDSerializer` in the fields attribute of the `Meta` class there is an `awd_source` field but you don't have such field in your `AwdModel`, change it to `source_zip`.

Comment: I have mentioned the **name** attribute for **AWDModel**'s  source_zip field as **awd_source**.

Comment: That's not what **name** is used for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name

Answer (score 1):

The code that you posted appears to be valid and correct. The issue however is unrelated. The exception text `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'project_id'` Refers to an issue that likely originates from your restframework app's views.py file. The exception states that you are attempting to access the attribute 'project_id' from a QuerySet.

A QuerySet is a (lazy loaded) set of models and not a single model. Even if the query set had only one element you'd still be required to access that element before accessing it's attributes.

Because you haven't shared your views.py file I can't say for sure where the issue is however **here is an incorrect use case example**: `MyModel.objects.all().project_id`. Here we can see that I am attempting to access the attribute `project_id` from a query set. A correct use case would be `MyModel.objects.all()[0].project_id`. However this assumes that the query set is not empty.

Practically, most DjangoRestFramework views inherit from `rest_framework.views.APIView` which subclasses django's View Class. I would suggest checking the `query_set` within that class is being used correctly.

Feel free to share your implementation here for further comment.

**[EDIT] - After views.py coded was added.**

You are attempting to serializer an entire query set with the instantiation of a serializer `data = AWDSerializer(deployments).data` this is causing the attribute error.

I would recommend the `generics.ListAPIView` class and the use of the class attributes `query_set` and `serializer_class`. These are simple to implement. You can then invoke the APIViews default get method. Here is an example for your `DeploymentsList view`

```
from rest_framework import generics

class DeploymentsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AWDSerializer
    queryset = AwdModel.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        MAX_OBJECTS = int(20)
        self.queryset = self.queryset[:MAX_OBJECTS]
        return super(DeploymentsList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**[EDIT] - FileField Serialization**
In order to serialize the UserAccount.credentials file field so that we serializer the path, we can use the `serializers.SerializerMethodField`. I.e Your UserAccountSerializer becomes:

```
class UserAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    credentials = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_credentials(self, user_account):
        return user_account.credentials.path

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccountModel
        fields = ('deployment_name', 'credentials', 'project_name',
                  'project_id', 'cluster_name', 'zone_region', 'services')
```

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I have added my **APIView** code, take a look, please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman I have added some information in response to your update in my answer above. My response contains the error explanation and a suggested alternative solution.

Comment: another error comes in: `Object of type 'FileField' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: can we send the file path instead of File in the response?

Comment: @AbdulRehman Yes we can, see the updates I've added in relation to File Field Serialization using a serialiser method field.

Comment: still, sending the same error, I'm confused about `user_acount` what we are passing as `user_account`?

Comment: Did you implement the generic list view? User account referred to a single instance of the user account model. That is, for every user account object that is serialised, the credentials serialiser method field will evaluate base on the credentials of that specific user account.

Comment: You can alternately use credentials.url if that better suits your needs

Comment: how can I use `credentials.url`? please!

Comment: Replace your serialiser with the implementation that I gave you, Django rest framework will take care of the rest. To use credential.url, replace path with url in the get_credentials method, Django rest framework automatically associated the seriliazer method field with this function.

Comment: I'm using the same implementations as you have provided above and also replaced 'path' with 'url' in `get_credentials` method, but it still returns the same error as: `TypeError at /api/v1/deployments/
Object of type 'FileField' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: No worries, I’ll update this comment with a response when I’m at my machine.

Comment: @AbdulRehman I understand you've implemented the serializer method field in the serializer, have you implemented the generics list view implementation which I gave you or are you still using `APIView`

Comment: @AbdulRehman I would also advise that you read the DRF documentation carefully. In my experience even when under time constraints you'll be better off seeking understanding before a solution.

Comment: I’m using generics list view

Comment: @AbdulRehman Could you please mark this question as resolved. I would suggest marking the answer that helped you the most as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError at /api/v1/deployments/ Got AttributeError when
>   attempting to get a value for field project_id on serializer
>   AWDSerializer. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not
>   match any attribute or key on the QuerySet instance. Original
>   exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'project_id'.

This is an attribute error, when attempting to get the value from field `project_id` .

Get rid of the `name` attribute in the `project_id` field.

**Edit The APIView code**

> To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object
>   instance, you should pass the many=True flag when instantiating the
>   serializer. You can then pass a queryset or list of objects to be
>   serialized. [[Serializing multiple objects](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)]

```
class DeploymentsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        MAX_OBJECTS = int(20)
        deployments = AwdModel.objects.all()[:MAX_OBJECTS]
        data = AWDSerializer(deployments, many=True).data
        return Response(data)
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hi @Yusef, I have tried it by removing the **name** attribute but still not working.

Comment: OK, but the exception is gone?

Comment: Check out the answer now.

Comment: @AbdulRehman all that will be stored in your database is a path to the file (relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`) see [FileField.storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)

Comment: so, how can we grab that path?

Comment: There is a `url` attribute provided by **Django**. used like this `credentials.url` **(FieldFile.url)**.

Comment: @AbdulRehman you’ll need to define `MEDIA_ROOT` (in **settings.py** file) as the full path to a directory where you’d like Django to store uploaded file.

Comment: I have defined this path in settings but how can i use this in serializers.py?

Comment: @AbdulRehman what do you want the `serializer` to return in `AWDSerializer(deployments, many=True).data` the `filename` or the `url`?

Comment: I need to return url!

Comment: @AbdulRehman that's the default behaviour, if for some reason it's not in your case try setting the config variable `UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL` to `True` in **settings.py** file

Comment: I have tries this but it still returns `Object of type 'FileField' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: it returns as: `TypeError at /api/v1/deployments/
Object of type 'FileField' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @AbdulRehman The `FileField` and `ImageField` classes are only suitable for use with `MultiPartParser` or `FileUploadParser`. Most parsers, such as e.g. JSON don't support file uploads.

Comment: But i simple needs the url of the file.

Comment: @AbdulRehman i know, but that's a `FileField` at the end. Do you have `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` `REST_FRAMEWORK` config, try adding `FileUploadParser`. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit from a model class which is not defined as [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#abstract) in it’s own meta class, then Django creates a one-to-one relation between the subclass and its parent.  Which actually creates two tables in the database; one for the base class and one for the subclass.

---

I haven’t tried your code, nor used Django 2, but would check using a relational field between the two serializer.